# Jquery bind doesnt work on AJAX loaded HTML

Tags: jquery, ajax, dom, bind

This is my jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready (function() {

   // post
    $('.post').bind('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).filter('.btn').toggleClass('hidden');
    });


});
```

It works great on a normal document. but When I load some HTM: (i.e some divs with .post attributes) using ajax and embed it into my DOM.

The above code doesnt work with those divs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using [live](http://api.jquery.com/live/):

```
jQuery(document).ready (function() {
    $('.post').live('mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).filter('.btn').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Or better yet [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/)

```
jQuery(document).ready (function() {
    $('#posts').delegate('.post','mouseenter mouseleave', function() {
        $(this).filter('.btn').toggleClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this one and its not working both on static and ajax loaded content as well. And I want it to actually work with both the static content and the loaded content in one shot.

Comment: Live or delegate should make it so that the event fires for static and loaded content.  There must be something else going on.

Comment: No lock.. I dont know what it is.. But bind works fine with static content and live and delegate doesnt seems to be working

Comment: Are you sure the content you are loading through the ajax call has the `.post` class?

Comment: My bad. I was on jquery 1.3.2 and it doesnt supported mouseover and mouseleave with live(). This works great ! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your timing is probably off as the div with `.post` attributes must actually exist in the dom before you can bind anything to it.

Comment: See if this helps you: http://api.jquery.com/delegate/ Use `$('body').delegate('.post','mouseenter mouseleave', f` etc

Comment: I mean 'body' as your selector or whatever outer element your divs are contained in.